# PDT/Xdebug with Firefox

Tags: eclipse, firefox, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

Are there any special instructions for getting PDT/Xdebug working with Firefox?

I've been able to get it working just fine with the internal browser as well as Chrome, but for some reason, with Firefox, I'm getting stuck at 57% while attempting to initiate the debug session.

I've had everything working with Firefox in the past, but unfortunately, my PC crashed and I'm starting from scratch.

I've changed the setting in Preferences > General > Web Browser to Firefox and have even let the search option scan the directory and it successfully finds the exe.

Not sure what else to check at this point. Doesn't seem to be an issue with the Eclipse/PDT/Xdebug config since it works fine with all other browsers I've tried.

Version info:

```
FF version 12.0
Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit)
Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2
PDT 3.0.0.v201201110400-77-184_2BEICRgM_fMVcz0M4Va9O
```

Xdebug info:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_log = C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/tmp
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

Comment: What is in your remote debug log?

Comment: @Derick Nothing ever did show up in my xdebug_log, but somehow it started working this morning. Seems to be one of those mystery issues that fixed itself somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this issue was as well, but after it working fine for a long time.
It may well be related to a new version of java 7_21 although I cannot see a good reason why that should cause a problem.

I solved it this way
[Eclipse, XAMPP, xDebug - waiting for XDebug session - stays in 57%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121672/eclipse-xampp-xdebug-waiting-for-xdebug-session-stays-in-57/16167484#16167484)

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing some problems while trying to debug with Firefox.

Then I found this Firefox add-on that adds support for Xdebug:

[easy Xdebug 1.5](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/)

In my case it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be one of those issues that "fixed itself". Not sure how, but it's working now.